# Correctly understanding cuda versioning and compatibility

Tags: cuda

CUDA programming guide states that:

```
the driver API is backward compatible, meaning that applications, plug-ins, and libraries (including the C runtime) compiled against a particular version of the driver API will continue to work on subsequent device driver releases
```

I understand this as that, if my code was compiled on CUDA4, the binary will run on CUDA5. However, it turned out that running the CUDA5-compiled binary on CUDA5 led to:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libcudart.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Note that I am using the "module" facility in Linux to switch in between different cuda versions, i.e.

```
module load cuda4
compile
module unload cuda4
module load cuda5
run
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the developers responsibility to package libcudart.so.4 with the application. The module command is likely changing your LD_LIBRARY_PATH or your PATH variable so LDD is not finding libcudart.so.4. I recommend you add a post build step to copy the required .so into your application directory.

ATTACHMENT A in EULA.txt at the root of the CUDA Toolkit directory lists the Redistributable Software. This includes libcudart.so (and variations that have version number information embedded in the file name). This also includes libcufft, libcublas, ...